# Secure access to CosmosDB from App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-virtual-network

I have a node.js app deployed to Azure App Services which uses CosmosDB for storing the application data. Everything works fine.

However, I would like to lock down access to the CosmosDB instance at the network level to secure the data better.

Following the documentation, I have setup a virtual network, added the app service app into it, setup a service endpoint for CosmosDB and restricted access to the DB instance to only allow the virtual network.

I have redone this multiple times, waited for everything to update (12-24 hours), but to no avail. I am consistently getting connection errors when the app attemps to call the DB once I implement the setup above.

Does anyone have any insights? I am pretty frustrated and contemplating moving to AWS instead, but my client is keen to do Azure for a number of different reasons.

Comment: Have you enabled firewall rules on your Cosmos DB account?

Comment: Not enough data to go on to say for sure what the issue is. My guess is the thing called out in the first "Note" in this article is the cause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-vnet-service-endpoint. Also not sure how you've set this up but here is a cli script that sets up service endpoints for an account in Cosmos. This might be helpful, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scripts/cli/common/service-endpoints.

Comment: @GauravMantri: Yes I have.

Comment: @MarkBrown: The subnet has a service endpoint for CosmosDB and my CosmosDB is setup to only accept traffic from that specific subnet. I can't really find anything in the documentation contradicting what I've done, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: From the link @MarkBrown shared...When a service endpoint for your Azure Cosmos DB account is enabled on a subnet, the source of the traffic that reaches Azure Cosmos DB switches from a public IP to a virtual network and subnet. The traffic switching applies for any Azure Cosmos DB account that's accessed from this subnet. **If your Azure Cosmos DB accounts have an IP-based firewall to allow this subnet, requests from the service-enabled subnet no longer match the IP firewall rules, and they're rejected**.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this? I am following MS documentation and created exactly the same setup, still not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, If you want to allow your app service to access the cosmos db inside Vnet. we need to integrate Vnet with app service with regional VNet Integration. After that, we can access the cosmos DB across service endpoints. But it cannot allow us to reach resources across global peering connections. It means that app service and cosmos db should be in the same region. For more details, please refer to the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#new-vnet-integration)

Besides, if you want to access resources across the different regions, I suggest you use the App service environment. Regarding the issue, please refer to the [article](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/28461)

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding as well. Everything is set up in the same region.

Comment: @JakobBøgh Could you please tell me if you use the same Vnet or different Vnet when you configure it and the app Vnet and cosmos db are in the same region?

Comment: App service is configured to a VNET (in the same region as both the app service and the ComosDB). CosmosDB service endpoint is activated for the VNET. CosmosDB has a firewall setting only allow traffic from the VNET in question.

Comment: @JakobBøgh Could you please provide the screenshot of the app service and cosmos db firewall?