# Azure CLI - Connect Web App to Azure Cosmos DB via private-endpoint

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I am creating an Azure devOps pipeline where the steps in the pipeline call Powershell scripts which in turn call the Az module(s) - this i can do and dont need help on.

Within the pipeline I am creating the Cosmos DB via the above method and in the next step creating a "private-endpoint" via calling "az network private-endpoint create" in the Powershell script - this workds and the endpoint is "approved".

I now need the Azure Web-App to connect to the Cosmos "private-endpoint". The web-app and the cosmos db are in their own subnets - both subnets are in the same vnet/location/resource-groups.

I need help in linking the Azure WebApp to the Cosmos DB private endpoint using CLI commands?

Comment: This article has been helpful...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910776/secure-access-to-cosmosdb-from-app-service

Answer (score 0):

For the Azure web-app I used vnet-integration and for the cosmos account I created in a backend-subnet in the same vnet as the web-app so the cosmos account only accepts traffic from the web-app subnet.